# How to set required false in symfony validation (yml) file

Tags: php, symfony

I have user.yml file in my validation folder in symfony and I am using it to validate the data. eg:

```
\APIBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    startDate:
        - NotBlank: { message: 'Start date cannot be blank.' }
        - Date: { message: 'Enter the valid start date.' }
```

I wanted to validate "startDate" field if user have passed it which is working now. But if user is not passed the "startDate" then I wanted to skip this validation. i.e Wanted the this validation as optional .

**How to achieve this ?**

I tried to set required false as following:

```
\APIBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    startDate:
        - Required: false
        - NotBlank: { message: 'Start date cannot be blank.' }
        - Date: { message: 'Enter the valid start date.' }
```

Which is not working symfony return the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `NotBlank`

```
\APIBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    startDate:
        - Date: { message: 'Enter the valid start date.' }
```

`NotBlank` is equivalent of `reqired`.

Answer (score 1):

required just affects rendering [see](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#required) :

> If true, an HTML5 required attribute will be rendered. The corresponding label will also render with a required class.
>
> This is superficial and independent from validation. At best, if you
>   let Symfony guess your field type, then the value of this option will
>   be guessed from your validation information.

you should use `empty_data` in your form like so :

```
$builder->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'm' => 'Male',
        'f' => 'Female'
    ),
    'required'    => false,
    'placeholder' => 'Choose your gender',
    'empty_data'  => null
));
```

Your entity in this case should have the property `nullable=true` and of course like mentionned `NotBlank` shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `NotBlank`, that field is always required. However, you only want to validate the field if it is actually set.

I think that you won't accomplish that with Symfony's built-in validation, but you could write your custom Validation Constraint that handles this case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html